# tx_form multiple times on one page via RECORDS

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

via TypoScript i generate a HTML-Table and on every line i add the same formular (tx_form formular) via RECORDS. The form can be opened in a lightbox and all is fine but when i submit one of these, all forms will be submit and i receive 16 mails.
How can i separate the forms? RECORDS is needed because i build the table in TypoScript and so i can update the form in the backend and all forms on the page are updated.
Is there a parameter which i can set unique via TypoScript for every record so every form is technical a single form?

Answer (score 0):

I would use some javascript to iterate over the forms and make them unique.

As this might conflict with the secutrity mechanism from TYPO3 you alternatively can use javascript to remove other than the currently clicked form from the page. This might need a reload from the page if you have no special answer page for the form.